# Gulp watch task only runs once

Tags: javascript, gulp

I've seen this question has been asked before and I've looked at the answers, but I can not get my head around what I'm doing wrong.

The first time I run `gulp watch` my less files compiles. The second time, I can see that the watch is running but my less files does not compile.

Less task

```
gulp.task('less', () => {
  gulp.src(['./src/less/**/*.less', './src/less/*.less'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
});
```

Watch task

```
gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch(['./src/less/**/*.less', './src/less/*.less'], ['less']);
  gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', ['js']);
});
```

What am I doin wrong?

Comment: What happens? How do you verify that its not compiling?

Comment: I check the css files and nothing has changed